# D3.js draw a line chart from 0 when there is no data

Tags: d3.js

The data set I want to plot has less data points than the xAxis ticks. i.e. I want to plot a chart from day 1 to day 7, but there is no data before day 4. Instead of the line chart appearing suddenly from day 4, is it possible to show the line from day 1 with value of 0 and link to the value on day 4?.

The current chart

[image]

My line chart is like below

```
svg.append("path").transition().duration(2500).attr("class", "line").attr("d", valueline(plotdata));
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Cant you just update your data-set and add the value 0 to all days that are missing data? Also, if you can provide an example in jsfiddle it will be easier to answer the question.

Comment: Edit the plot data before plotting it to check if data is at day 1, if not, add the data

Comment: Just edit the data?